# Null pointer Exception while calling Asynctask situated inside fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-context

I am facing a Null pointer Exception while calling Create report (which in turns calls its Asynctask "createReportTask" situated inside the Activity) But the application crashes giving NPE in the other fragment's Asynsc task (situated inside fragment) , I have tried passing context in constructor etc getContext(), getAcitivity() etc but all in vain. I am attaching Logs and Code please help!!

Logs:

```
    05-24 12:56:11.505 14632-14632/com.example.aiousecurityapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.aiousecurityapplication, PID: 14632
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference
        at android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:121)
        at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:291)
        at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:281)
        at com.example.aiousecurityapplication.Activities.EventsReportFragment$MakeRequestTask.onPostExecute(EventsReportFragment.java:439)
        at com.example.aiousecurityapplication.Activities.EventsReportFragment$MakeRequestTask.onPostExecute(EventsReportFragment.java:377)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:727)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:744)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:108)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:166)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7425)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:245)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:921)
```

Create Report Code:

```
    public class CreateReport extends AppCompatActivity {
    public EditText eventDate;
    public EditText eventTime;
    EditText reporterName;
    EditText reporterCnic;
    int flag = 0;

    public static Calendar userCalendar;
    private String Lat, Long;
    private static final String[] BLOCK = new String[]{"Block 1", "Block 2", "Block 3", "Block 4", "Block 5"};
    private static final String[] sampleDesc = new String[]{"Aag Lagi ha", "Darwaza Khula h", "Tala Ni Laga", "Lights / Fan On hain"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_report);
        Button createReport = (Button) findViewById(R.id.createReport);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        this.getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        final ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
        ab.setTitle("Create Report");
        String myFormat1 = "yyyy-MM-dd";
        String myFormat2 = "HH:mm";
        SimpleDateFormat mainSdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat(myFormat1, Locale.US);
        SimpleDateFormat mainSdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat(myFormat2, Locale.US);


        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

                 if (bundle != null) {
            Lat = bundle.getString("lat");
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Latitude" + Lat, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Long = bundle.getString("Long");
        }
        createReport.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (eventDescription.getText().toString().length() < 3) {
                    eventDescription.setError("Minimum 5 Letters");
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Please some Description", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                } else {
                    // creating new product in background thread

                    String blockname = blockName.getSelectedItem().toString().trim();
                    String eventEsc = eventEsclation.getSelectedItem().toString().trim();
                    String eventdesc = eventDescription.getText().toString().trim();
                    String cnic = reporterCnic.getText().toString().trim();
                    String userLat = Lat;
                    String userLong = Long;
                    String date = eventDate.getText().toString().trim();
                    String time = eventTime.getText().toString().trim();
                    new createReportTask().execute(blockname, eventEsc, eventdesc, cnic, userLat, userLong, date, time);
                }

            }
        });

    }

    public class createReportTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {
        private JSONSenderReceiver jsonparser = new JSONSenderReceiver();
        ProgressDialog pDialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            Log.d("Creating Report", "in Pre Execute");
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(CreateReport.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Creating Report");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            try {
                if (result == null) {
                pDialog.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(CreateReport.this, "No response from server.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }

                Log.d("Response from server: ", result.toString());
                int success = Integer.parseInt(result.getString("status"));
                String message = result.getString("message");

                if (success == 2) {

                    Toast.makeText(CreateReport.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            pDialog.dismiss();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        /**
         * Creating product
         */
        protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {

            String blockName = args[0] != null ? args[0] : "";
            String eventEscalation = args[1];
            String eventDesc = args[2];
            String userCnic = args[3];
            String userLat = args[4];
            String userLong = args[5];
            String date = args[6];
            String time = args[7];

            if (blockName.trim().length() != 0 && eventEscalation.trim().length() != 0
                    && eventDesc.trim().length() != 0 && userCnic.trim().length() != 0 && userLat.trim().length() != 0
                    && userLong.trim().length() != 0 && date.trim().length() != 0 && time.trim().length() != 0) {
                //db field name in value side

                // Building Parameters

                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("page", "datasync"));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("blockName", blockName));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("eventEscalation", eventEscalation));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("eventDesc", eventDesc));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userCnic", userCnic));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userLat", userLat));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userLong", userLong));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("date", date));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("time", time));

                // getting JSON Object
                // Note that create product url accepts POST method
                return jsonparser.makeHttpRequest(AppConfig.URL_MAIN, "POST", params);
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Fragment Code:

```
    public class EventsReportFragment extends Fragment {
    static final int REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION = 1001;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private static final int REQUEST_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE = 34;
    private boolean mAlreadyStartedService = false;
    private TextView mMsgView;
    View rootView;
    String latitude;
    String longitude;
    String myFormat1 = "yyyy-MM-dd";
    String myFormat2 = "HH:mm:ss";
    SimpleDateFormat mainSdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat(myFormat1, Locale.US);
    SimpleDateFormat mainSdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat(myFormat2, Locale.US);

    public EventsReportFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getContext()).registerReceiver(
                new BroadcastReceiver() {
                    @Override
                    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                        latitude = intent.getStringExtra(LocationMonitoringService.EXTRA_LATITUDE);
                        longitude = intent.getStringExtra(LocationMonitoringService.EXTRA_LONGITUDE);
                        new MakeRequestTask().execute(AppSettings.getUserCnic(), latitude, longitude,
                                mainSdf1.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()),
                                mainSdf2.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()));

                        if (latitude != null && longitude != null) {
                            mMsgView.setText("msg_location_service_started" + "\n Latitude : " + latitude + "\n Longitude: " + longitude);
                        }
                    }
                }, new IntentFilter(LocationMonitoringService.ACTION_LOCATION_BROADCAST)
        );
    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_events_list, container, false);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        mMsgView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById (R.id.msgView);
        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), CreateReport.class);
                intent.putExtra("lat", latitude);
                intent.putExtra("long", longitude);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        return rootView;

    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        startStep1();
    }


    /**
     * Step 1: Check Google Play services
     */
    private void startStep1() {

        //Check whether this user has installed Google play service which is being used by Location updates.
        if (isGooglePlayServicesAvailable()) {

            //Passing null to indicate that it is executing for the first time.
            startStep2(null);

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "no_google_playservice_available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }


    /**
     * Step 2: Check & Prompt Internet connection
     */
    private Boolean startStep2(DialogInterface dialog) {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager
                = (ConnectivityManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();

        if (activeNetworkInfo == null || !activeNetworkInfo.isConnected()) {
            promptInternetConnect();
            return false;
        }


        if (dialog != null) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }


        if (checkPermissions()) { //Yes permissions are granted by the user. Go to the next step.
            startStep3();
        } else {  //No user has not granted the permissions yet. Request now.
            requestPermissions();
        }
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Show A Dialog with button to refresh the internet state.
     */
    private void promptInternetConnect() {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
        builder.setTitle("title_alert_no_intenet");
        builder.setMessage("msg_alert_no_internet");

        String positiveText = "Refresh Button";
        builder.setPositiveButton(positiveText,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {


                        //Block the Application Execution until user grants the permissions
                        if (startStep2(dialog)) {

                            //Now make sure about location permission.
                            if (checkPermissions()) {

                                //Step 2: Start the Location Monitor Service
                                //Everything is there to start the service.
                                startStep3();
                            } else if (!checkPermissions()) {
                                requestPermissions();
                            }

                        }
                    }
                });

        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * Step 3: Start the Location Monitor Service
     */
    private void startStep3() {

        //And it will be keep running until you close the entire application from task manager.
        //This method will executed only once.

        if (!mAlreadyStartedService && mMsgView != null) {

            mMsgView.setText("Location_service_started");

            //Start location sharing service to app server.........
            Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), LocationMonitoringService.class);
            getActivity().startService(intent);

            mAlreadyStartedService = true;
            //Ends................................................
        }
    }

    /**
     * Return the availability of GooglePlayServices
     */
    public boolean isGooglePlayServicesAvailable() {
        GoogleApiAvailability googleApiAvailability = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
        int status = googleApiAvailability.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getContext());
        if (status != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            if (googleApiAvailability.isUserResolvableError(status)) {
                googleApiAvailability.getErrorDialog(getActivity(), status, 2404).show();
            }
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }


    /**
     * Return the current state of the permissions needed.
     */
    private boolean checkPermissions() {
        int permissionState1 = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(),
                android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);

        int permissionState2 = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(),
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION);

        return permissionState1 == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && permissionState2 == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;

    }

    /**
     * Start permissions requests.
     */
    private void requestPermissions() {

        boolean shouldProvideRationale =
                ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(getActivity(),
                        android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);

        boolean shouldProvideRationale2 =
                ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(getActivity(),
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION);


        // Provide an additional rationale to the img_user. This would happen if the img_user denied the
        // request previously, but didn't check the "Don't ask again" checkbox.
        if (shouldProvideRationale || shouldProvideRationale2) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Displaying permission rationale to provide additional context.");
            showSnackbar(R.string.permission_rationale,
                    android.R.string.ok, new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            // Request permission
                            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(),
                                    new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},
                                    REQUEST_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE);
                        }
                    });
        } else {
            Log.i(TAG, "Requesting permission");
            // Request permission. It's possible this can be auto answered if device policy
            // sets the permission in a given state or the img_user denied the permission
            // previously and checked "Never ask again".
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(),
                    new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},
                    REQUEST_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    }


    /**
     * Shows a {@link Snackbar}.
     *
     * @param mainTextStringId The id for the string resource for the Snackbar text.
     * @param actionStringId   The text of the action item.
     * @param listener         The listener associated with the Snackbar action.
     */
    private void showSnackbar(final int mainTextStringId, final int actionStringId,
                              View.OnClickListener listener) {
        Snackbar.make(
                rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.content),
                getString(mainTextStringId),
                Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
                .setAction(getString(actionStringId), listener).show();
    }

    /**
     * Callback received when a permissions request has been completed.
     */
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions,
                                           @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onRequestPermissionResult");
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (grantResults.length <= 0) {
                // If img_user interaction was interrupted, the permission request is cancelled and you
                // receive empty arrays.
                Log.i(TAG, "User interaction was cancelled.");
            } else if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                Log.i(TAG, "Permission granted, updates requested, starting location updates");
                startStep3();

            } else {

                showSnackbar(R.string.permission_denied_explanation,
                        R.string.settings, new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View view) {
                                // Build intent that displays the App settings screen.
                                Intent intent = new Intent();
                                intent.setAction(
                                        Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
                                Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package",
                                        BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID, null);
                                intent.setData(uri);
                                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                                startActivity(intent);
                            }
                        });
            }
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {


        //Stop location sharing service to app server.........

        getActivity().stopService(new Intent(getActivity(), LocationMonitoringService.class));
        mAlreadyStartedService = false;
        //Ends................................................


        super.onDestroy();
    }


    public class MakeRequestTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {

        private Exception mLastError = null;
        private JSONSenderReceiver jsonparser = new JSONSenderReceiver();

        public MakeRequestTask() {

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

        }


        @Override
        protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {
            try {
                String cnic = args[0];
                String userLat = args[1];
                String userLong = args[2];
                String date = args[3];
                String time = args[4];

                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

                if (cnic.trim().length() != 0 && userLat.trim().length() != 0
                        && userLong.trim().length() != 0 && date.trim().length() != 0 && time.trim().length() != 0) {

                    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("page", "locationUpdate"));
                    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("cnic", cnic));
                    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userLat", userLat));
                    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userLong", userLong));
                    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("date", date));
                    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("time", time));
                }
                return jsonparser.makeHttpRequest(AppConfig.URL_MAIN, "POST", params);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                mLastError = e;
                cancel(true);
                return null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            try {
                if (result == null) {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "No response from server.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }

                Log.d("Response from server: ", result.toString());
                int success = Integer.parseInt(result.getString("status"));
                String message = result.getString("message");

                if (success == 1) {

                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                } else if (success == 2){

                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCancelled() {

        }

    }

}``
```

Answer (score 0):

In onPostExecute check for activity is running before doing any work.
because onPostExecute may be called if activity was running not more

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_events_list, container, false);

 LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity()).registerReceiver(
            new BroadcastReceiver() {
                @Override
                public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                    latitude = intent.getStringExtra(LocationMonitoringService.EXTRA_LATITUDE);
                    longitude = intent.getStringExtra(LocationMonitoringService.EXTRA_LONGITUDE);
                    new MakeRequestTask().execute(AppSettings.getUserCnic(), latitude, longitude,
                            mainSdf1.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()),
                            mainSdf2.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()));

                    if (latitude != null && longitude != null) {
                        mMsgView.setText("msg_location_service_started" + "\n Latitude : " + latitude + "\n Longitude: " + longitude);
                    }
                }
            }, new IntentFilter(LocationMonitoringService.ACTION_LOCATION_BROADCAST)
    );
   //your remaining code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use following line:

```
String message = result.optString("message");
// it will returns the empty string ("") if the key you specify doesn't exist
```

instead of using

```
String message = result.getString("message");
// it will throws exception if the key you specify doesn't exist
```

Answer (score 0):

replace     `getContext()` with     `getActivity()`  inside your fragment

e.g replace 
  
`Toast.makeText(getContext(), "no_google_playservice_available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();`

with

```
 `Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "no_google_playservice_available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();`
```

and

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getContext()).registerReceiver(
```

with

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity()).registerReceiver(
```

and so on if any.

Comment: I have passed context in the constructor of my AsyncTask (both in CreateReport and EventListFragment) and changed getContext() with getActivity everywhere inside fragment but still, the same issue remains.